# Can JavaScript Functions Auto Detect and Log their Execution Cycle

Tags: function

Supposing I want to know execution time expended for a function to complete its execution cycle, I know that I would need to run:

```
function runcycle(){
  console.time('runcycle', console.log('runcycle started'));
  //function body
  return console.timeEnd('runcycle');
}
```

This is however manual and cumbersome, especially if I have multiple functions, so my question is this:

**Is it possible for JavaScript functions run automated timer messages about their execution?**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems there is an easy workaround to achieve auto logger for function execution, which is by creating a helper function that wraps all functions in a host function:

```
function logfunc(func, fname){
  return function(){
    console.time(fname, console.log(fname, 'started'));
    let r = func();
    console.timeEnd(fname);
    return r;
  }
}
/* And the helper logfunc can be utilized as: */
let test = logfunc(()=>{//funcbody}, 'test');

/* test() will run normally, but with logger capabilities */
test();
}
```

Though this works, I am still open to learning if JavaScript has an inbuilt auto logger for functions.